# How do I structure a card header in bootstrap 4 to keep three elements in a row, truncating the text in the middle element for smaller screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have a series of cards that I'm using for an accordion. Each card has a card header and a card body.

Each card header has four elements: an `<i>` for a carat icon, an `<h4>` with the title of the card, an `<input>` for receiving data from the user, and a final `<h4>` that is merely a % character.

The desired outcome is that the `<i>` and first `<h4>` float left, and that the text of the  will fill the space inline that's not consumed by the other three elements, but truncate across all device sizes as necessary. The `<input>` and final `<h4>` should not resize and should always stay on the end of the line. All four elements must always stay on the same line and never stack.

I've now spent six hours scouring the documentation and various blogs and have not gotten this to work. I've tried `.d-flex`, `.clearfix`, `.float-left/right`, various combinations of containers, rows and columns. Common problems are getting the first two elements to float left and the second two to float right, as well as getting the `.text-truncate` to actually function. Not to mention getting the  title element to fill the available space.

How should I structure the cards to always get the desired result?

Here's a snippet of the card header code:

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                <div class="row" style="display: block;">
                    <i class="far fa-caret-square-down fa-2x mr-1"></i>
                    <h4 class="text-truncate">Education, Emp., Social Services</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center">
                <input type="number" name="cat-edTrainEmp" class="form-control-sm mr-1 survey" id="cat-edTrainEmp" max="100" min="0" required><h4>%</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The desired card header output should look and act like this:
[card header structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rlwl.png)

Comment: Hi! I tried to open the accordion but the get started button isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the formatting problems by eliminating the `.row` and `.column` classes from the card. I also applied the `.d-flex` class to the card-header which helped. This eliminated all of the unwanted stacking. The `.text-truncate` problem can be solved by removing the link reference that spans two other tags and applying the link individually to each element. The functional code is below:

```
<div class="card-header d-flex">
  <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
    <i class="far fa-caret-square-down fa-2x mr-1"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="card-link text-truncate mr-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
    <h4 class="text-truncate">Income Security</h4>
  </a>
  <input type="number" name="cat-incomeSec" class="form-control-sm survey ml-1" id="cat-incomeSec" max="100" min="0" required>
  <h4 class="">%</h4>
</div>
```